# dotplot in R with lattice: display of vertical axis and error bars

Tags: r, data-visualization, lattice

I'm trying to do a dotplot with the libraries `lattice` and `latticeExtra` in `R`. However, no proper representation of the values on the vertical y-axis is done. Instead of choosing the actual values of the numeric variable, `R` plots the rank of the value. That is, there are values `[375, 500, 625, 750, ..., 3000]` and `R` plots their ranks `[1,2,3,4,...23]` and chooses the scale accordingly. Has someone experienced a problem like this? How can I manage the get a proper representation with ticks like `(0, 500, 1000, 1500, ...)` on the vertical y-scale?

Here the program code so far:

```
df.dose <- read.table("data.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)
library(lattice); library(latticeExtra)

useOuterStrips(dotplot(z ~ sample.size | as.factor(effect.size)*as.factor(true.dose),
               groups=as.factor(type), data=df.dose, as.table=TRUE))
```

(Added from comment below): Also, can error bars be added to the graph? I thought of the following (to be added to the call), but it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible somehow?

```
up=z+se, lo=z-se, panel.groups=function(x,y,..., up, lo, subscripts){ 
   up <- up[subscripts]
   lo <- lo[subscripts]
   panel.segments(lo, as.numeric(y), up, as.numeric(y), ...)
}
```

Here's my data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/egy25cj00rhum40/data.csv

Added: here's the relevant portion of the data using `expand.grid` and `dput`:

```
df.dose <- expand.grid(effect.size=c(-.5, -.625, -0.75),
                       sample.size=c(40L, 60L, 80L),
                       true.dose=c(375L, 500L, 750L, 1125L),
                       type=c("dose", "categ", "FP2", "FP1"))
df.dose$z <- c(875L, 875L, 750L, 750L, 750L, 625L, 625L, 625L, 625L, 875L, 
875L, 750L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1125L, 1000L, 875L, 1000L, 1000L, 
875L, 1000L, 1000L, 875L, 1125L, 1000L, 1000L, 1250L, 1125L, 
1000L, 1250L, 1250L, 1125L, 1250L, 1000L, 1000L, 500L, 500L, 
500L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 625L, 625L, 625L, 625L, 
625L, 625L, 625L, 625L, 625L, 750L, 750L, 625L, 750L, 750L, 750L, 
750L, 750L, 750L, 875L, 875L, 750L, 750L, 875L, 875L, 875L, 875L, 
875L, 2500L, 1500L, 1125L, 2000L, 1000L, 1750L, 250L, 500L, 500L, 
1250L, 750L, 625L, 875L, 500L, 500L, 875L, 500L, 375L, 1250L, 
875L, 750L, 1000L, 625L, 625L, 875L, 500L, 500L, 1125L, 1000L, 
875L, 1125L, 875L, 625L, 1125L, 1000L, 625L, 2500L, 2125L, 2375L, 
2000L, 750L, 2625L, 250L, 625L, 250L, 875L, 875L, 500L, 625L, 
500L, 625L, 1000L, 500L, 375L, 1000L, 875L, 625L, 875L, 500L, 
500L, 875L, 500L, 500L, 1250L, 1125L, 875L, 1125L, 875L, 750L, 
1250L, 1000L, 625L)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make`z` a factor: `dotplot(factor(z) ~ ...`

Also you probably want some jitter in the plot to prevent overlap; try adding `jitter.x=TRUE` or `jitter.y=TRUE`, or both.

Judging by your comment below and looking at the data again, I think you're plotting the dotplot the wrong way.  I think you want the lines to be for the sample sizes, not for the `z`'s.  If you really want `z` on the vertical axis, you then need to add `horizontal=TRUE`.  You could also swap what is on the horizontal and vertical axes.

```
useOuterStrips(dotplot(z ~ factor(sample.size) | 
                             as.factor(effect.size)*as.factor(true.dose),
                  groups=as.factor(type), data=df.dose,  
                  as.table=TRUE, horizontal=FALSE, jitter.x=TRUE))
```

To add an error bar, it's a little more complicated because you have groups within the panels, so you need to use a `panel.groups` function; additionally, so that the lines don't overlap, you probably want to jitter them from side to side a little, which is best done in a custom `panel` function.

```
df.dose$se <- 200
df.dose$type <- factor(df.dose$type)
df.dose$sample.size <- factor(df.dose$sample.size)

panel.groups.mydotplot <- function(x, y, subscripts, up, lo, 
                                   col=NA, col.line=NA, ...) {
  panel.points(x, y, ...)
  panel.segments(x, lo[subscripts], x, up[subscripts], col=col.line, ...)
}
panel.mydotplot <- function(x, y, subscripts, groups, ..., jitter=0.1) {
  jitter <- seq(-1,1,len=nlevels(groups))*jitter
  xx <- as.numeric(x) + jitter[as.numeric(groups[subscripts])]
  panel.dotplot(x, y, groups=groups, subscripts=subscripts, pch=NA, ...)
  panel.superpose(xx, y, groups=groups, subscripts=subscripts,  
                  panel.groups=panel.groups.mydotplot, ...)
}
pp <- dotplot(z ~ sample.size | as.factor(effect.size)*as.factor(true.dose),
              groups=type, data=df.dose, as.table=TRUE, horizontal=FALSE,
              up=df.dose$z + df.dose$se, lo=df.dose$z - df.dose$se,
              panel=panel.mydotplot, auto.key=list(space="right"))
useOuterStrips(pp)
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Aaron, thanks a lot for your reply! Indeed, making the variable "z" a factor was the straightforward solution! Thank you therefore. However, when I try to customized the scales, ".R" shows no scale at all: scales=list(y=list(tick.number=6, relation="same", at=c(0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500)), x=list(tick.number=3, relation="same", at=c(40,60,80))

Comment: Yes, now it looks as it should be. Thanks a lot, this was really helpful!

Comment: Using "lattice", can error bars be added to the graph? I thought of "up=z+se, lo=z-se, panel.groups=function(x,y,..., up, lo, subscripts){ up <- up[subscripts]; lo <- lo[subscripts]; panel.segments(lo, as.numeric(y), up, as.numeric(y), ...)}", but that doesn't seem to work. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: For additional parameters, it doesn't look inside the `data`, so you have to input them as `up=df.dose$z + df.dose$se`.  Also your segments call will be right only if you've switched the axes; if you're using `horizontal=FALSE` you need to switch the arguments around appropriately.

Comment: Actually, it's a little more complicated because you have groups inside the panels.  See edit.

Comment: whow, very very nice! This was very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @Andres.  If one of these answers solved your problem, please click the check mark by it to let others know that's what worked for you.  You can also click the up arrow by any answer (even the one you checked) to signify that it was helpful, even if it's not the one that you used.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem and you asked for a lattice solution but I thought it may be helpful to see this done with ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data=df.dose, aes(x=sample.size, y=as.factor(z), colour=type)) +
    geom_point() + facet_grid(true.dose~effect.size)
```

Yields:
[image]

Or we can free the scales with:

```
ggplot(data=df.dose, aes(x=sample.size, y=as.factor(z), colour=type)) +
    geom_point() + facet_grid(true.dose~effect.size, scales="free")
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: Nice, Tyler.  How would you add jitter with ggplot to show the overlapping points?  (Or would some other method be preferred in ggplot?)

Comment: @Aaron you could use something like `position=position_jitter(width=.005)` inside of `geom_point` or mess with `alpha` the transparency (kinda) of the points.  I think there may be a better way to set up plotting this all together.  Perhaps faceting differently (by type) instead or creating a new variable that merges z and type.

Comment: Dear Tyler, thanks for the hint with ggplot. It looks very nice. I haven't thought of a way to do this in ggplot. Anyways, jitter is possible by adding "position=position_jitter(width=5,height=0)" into the brackets of geom_point()

Comment: Using "ggplot2", can error bars be added to the graph? I thought of "geom_segment(aes(x=sample.size, xend=sample.size, y=z-100, yend=z+100))", but that doesn't seem to work with the facet grid. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: And how could horizontal lines for each facet row be added, that is, separate lines for each panel of true.dose (375,500,750,1125)? I thought of creating a data frame that is called in geom_hline(..., data=...), but somehow the plot is distorted.

Comment: For error bars you'd use `geom_errorbar` [(LINK)](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_errorbar.html).  I'm not really sure what you're after on the second request.  Perhaps you want `geom_hline` [(LINK)](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_hline.html)

Comment: yes, geom_errorbar and geom_hline are appropriate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `xYplot` from the [package Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html), to achieve solution similar to @Aaron, although it might be a bit tricky to get the same jitter he got:

```
a <- xYplot(Cbind(z, z-se, z+se) ~ sample.size | as.factor(effect.size) * as.factor(true.dose),
            groups=as.factor(type), data=df.dose, as.table=TRUE, auto.key=list(space="top"))
useOuterStrips(a)
```

[image]

But is really informative plot? Does it show your data effects well, highlights your comparisons? Does it explore any trends in the data? To better see all the factors you want to plot, I would first make lines connections between your groups, to better see individual  effects within different `sample.size`.

```
key.variety <- list(space = "top", 
                    text = list(levels(df.dose$type)),
                    points = list(pch = 0:3, col = "black"))
a <- xyplot(z ~ as.factor(sample.size) | as.factor(effect.size)*as.factor(true.dose),
            df.dose, type = "o", as.table=TRUE, groups = type, key = key.variety, 
            lty = 1, pch = 0:3, col.line = "darkgrey", col.symbol = "black")
useOuterStrips(a)
```

[image]

But there is something hiding there and there is still too much noise because of the density of data. Let's get rid of the `effect.size` and plot regression line, although it's probably a sin to do with so few data points.

```
a <- xyplot(z ~ as.factor(sample.size) | as.factor(type)*as.factor(true.dose), 
            data=df.dose, as.table=TRUE, 
            panel = function(x, y){
               panel.xyplot(x, y, jitter.x = T, col=1);
               panel.lmline(x, y, col=1, lwd=1.5);
            })
useOuterStrips(a)
```

[image]

I know I might have not convinced you, but sometimes it's better to unload a plot from too many factors to get better look at the data. Sometimes it might be more accessible visually if you show the factors separated.

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the Hmisc-package. I see, there are many ways to accomplish this goal. Thanks a lot!